# Pylint in Visual Studio Code complaining about importing "sh" module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

Need a help that I am having issue of using Pylint  in visual studio code and not sure how to solve it.

[image]

The red line complains that:

```
[pylint] E1101:Module 'sh' has no 'helm' member
```

self: Helm

Comment: What is sh? Does it have a Helm attribute? Add why are you setting a module as an instance variable anyway?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @DanielRoseman https://amoffat.github.io/sh/

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the info and I'll pay attention next time since I would like to show the red line hinted by visual code (pylint)

Answer (score 1):

`sh` does weird things with `sys.modules` and `__getattr__` to generate attributes dynamically. PyLint doesn't understand that. Tell it stop checking attribute access on `sh` with the [`ignored-modules` option](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/features.html#typecheck-checker) in your `pylintrc`:

```
[TYPECHECK]
ignored-modules=sh
```

Comment: It's helpful. BTW, do you know how to setup pylintrc in virtrualenv by any chance?

Comment: @HAO: As far as I can tell, you do it the same way you would without a virtualenv, but I haven't looked into it deeply.